# Avoid returning data when using Nvim-R RDSendSelection and data.table `:=`

Tags: r, vim, data.table

When creating or updating columns with `:=` in `data.table`, the result is returned invisibly. Thus, when running the code below, no data is returned and only the graphic displayed.

Using [Nvim-R](https://github.com/jalvesaq/Nvim-R) reproduces this behaviour when each line is called with `RDSendLine`. However, if all lines are highlighted and executed with `RDSendSelection` data is returned also in the line with `:=`. How can this be avoided?

```
library(data.table)
library(lattice)
x <- 1:100
y <- runif(100, 0, 100)
d.data <- data.table(x = x, y = y)
d.data[, z := x * y]                  # Output created
d.data <- d.data[, z := x * y]        # no Output
invisible(d.data[, z := x * y])       # no Output
xyplot(y ~ x)
```

Any hint very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The provider of the Nvim-R plugin to vim [answered this question](https://github.com/jalvesaq/Nvim-R/issues/524)

Using `let R_source_args = 'print.eval = FALSE'`
does not print evalueated output and therefore avoids output from statements with ':='. As a side effect, all other output is also omitted; eg. `head(d.data)`, `plot(x~y, d.data)`.